# Linq Find method as IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have this in my repository and it works as expected:

```
public virtual EntityClass GetById(int id)
{
    return db.Set<EntityClass>().Find(id);
}
```

However, I have some tables with either too many columns (example: 10 columns where I need only 3 out of them) or some tables where I have long text in there and again, they dont need to be fetched.

I was thinking if there is a way to still search by the primary key but perhaps getting an IQueryable result? Or at least something that could allow me to do something like this:

```
var blah = myRepo.GetById(myId).Select(s => new {column 2, column 3, column 7})
```

Comment: As find searches by primary key (thus returning exactly one entity) - why would you need an `IQueryAble` return value?

Comment: Doesn't getting an IQueryable from Find defeat the purpose? Find is usually used to avoid making a trip to the database. What are you trying to optimize here?

Comment: `Find` is a bit special in that it will first check in the `StateManager` before going off to the Db (Store) to find the object, meaning it is potentially cached and must have all fields returned. If you want optimal sql (e.g. to hit a narrow index rather than the table), use a where with a select projection, or if you want to use `Find`, you'll need to manually map the full entity to a lite or anon class (but there seems little point, as it should be cheap to reuse the whole entity).

Comment: Guys, all that I need is a way to search a table byt its primary key (without knowing the table or pk name and being able to select a certain number of properties (columns) without getting them all.

Answer (score 1):

I would create another class that contains the subset of the properties that you want. That way it should always be clear what you are working with:

```
public class EntityClassLite
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Column2 {get; set;}
   public string Column3 {get; set;}
   public string Column7 {get; set;}
}
```

Then you could have a separate method in your repository:

```
public EntityClassLite GetLiteById(int id)
{
    return db.Set<EntityClass>()
             .All
             .Where(e => e.Id = id)
             .Select( new EntityClassLite
                    {
                       Column2 = e.Column2
                       Column3 = e.Column3
                       Column7 = e.Column7
                    }
             .FirstOrDefault()
}
```

You could also think about using inheritance:

```
public class EntityClass: EntityClassLite
{
   public string Column1 {get; set;}
   public string Column4 {get; set;}
   public string Column5 {get; set;}
   public string Column6 {get; set;}
   public string Column8 {get; set;}
   public string Column9 {get; set;}
   public string Column10 {get; set;}
}
```

Then you would have two repositories. One for `EntityClass` and one for `EntityClassLite`, each with their own `Find` method and each returning the data you require.

As an aside, I find it very hard to imagine an entity that has such large columns that fetching a single instance of it would cause significant performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you should reconsider using repository (if you're using *EF*) and move your fetching *logic* inside specific method like `GetEmployeeById(int id)` into *Service* layer.

And here's a quote about what happens if you're using repository along with *Entity Framework*.

> You've given up all the features of your data storage technology, for a bland, neutered, inefficient way of accessing your data. - *Khalid Abuhakmeh*

Answer (score 0):

```
var blah = myRepo.Where(s => s.Id == myId).Select(s => new {column 2, column 3, column 7}).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you plan to include the Id in the select you can do:

```
var blah = myRepo.Select(s => new {column 2, column 3, column 7}).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == myId);
```

Comment: Mikael, the s in the FirstOrDefault only gives me access to the items selected in the anonymous select. This is not what I need. thanks for trying though

Comment: As I wrote you use the first one if you don't include the Id in the projection and the second one if you did.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I read your answer again. But that will force me to select the Id just to be able to compare it later on. Not really what I am after.

Comment: No. If you don't want the Id, use the first version where the filtering is done in the Where clause before the Select.

Comment: Well, if I have to run the where clauses outside the repository, it defeats the purpose of having the repo. I thought it would be a tricky one. The problem is that the Find method fetches all the columns which in our application, there is a performance impact.